# Factorisation question.

Tags: polynomials

I was going through a math worksheet and I am stuck at this question:

> Factors of $(x^4 + 4)$:

Can someone tell me how to factorise this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you learn complex numbers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Factor $x^4+1$ over $\mathbb{R}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698827/factor-x41-over-mathbbr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$x^4+4=(x^4+4x^2+4)-4x^2$$
Difference of squares.

Comment: I feel so stupid right now.... Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Siddhant: No need to! It's not that obvious if you've not seen it before.

Answer (score 2):

This is a special case of the Sophie Germain Identity which states that $$a^4+4\cdot b^4 = (a^2+2ab+2b^2)(a^2-2ab+2b^2)$$

Applied to the case $x^4+4$ we have the factorization $(x^2+2x+2)(x^2-2x+2)$.

Answer (score 2):

You can address this using complex numbers.

$$x^4+4=0\iff x^4=-4$$so you need to consider the fourth roots of $-4$.

These are $\sqrt2e^{i\pi/4+ik\pi}$, i.e. $1+i,-1+i,-1-i,1-i$.

Taking them in conjugate pairs,

$$(x-1-i)(x-1+i)=(x^2-2x+2)$$and$$(x+1-i)(x+1+i)=(x^2+2x+2).$$

These are the requested factors.

Answer (score 1):

By indeterminate coefficients.

You see that the polynomial has no real roots, and it will factor as two quadratic trinomials.

$$x^4+1=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)=x^4+(a+c)x^3+(ac+b+d)x^2+(ad+bc)x+bd.$$

Then by identification,
$$\begin{align}a+c&=0\\ac+b+d&=0\\ad+bc&=0\\bd&=4.\end{align}$$
Observe $c=-a$, then $ad-ab=0\implies d=b$, $b^2=4\implies b=2$, $-a^2+2b=0\implies a=2$.

Solution:
$$(x^2+2x+2)(x^2-2x+2).$$